# jquery bind nprogress globally

Tags: jquery

I have tons of $.ajax calls in my system and now I need to have a special progress bar to be shown on any ajax request. Doing it for every request is too time-consumption task, can I do that in one place and how?

What I did so far

```
<script>

    // Show the progress bar
    NProgress.start();

    // Increase randomly
    var interval = setInterval(function() { NProgress.inc(); }, 1000);

    // Trigger finish when page fully loaded
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
        NProgress.done();
    });

    // Trigger bar when exiting the page
    jQuery(window).unload(function () {
        NProgress.start();
    });

</script>
```

It works on page load, I want the same to work on any ajax request without modifying existing scripts.

Comment: This question is way too broad, Please take a minute to read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe [Writing the perfect question.](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and try writing a better question, showing us what you have tried already and where you are stuck. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [ajaxStart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) & [ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) method like this

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  NProgress.start();
});

jQuery( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  NProgress.done();
});
```